# Ограничить количество максимально работающих потоков без ThreadPool

Tags: c#, многопоточность

К делу. Так это работает в ThreadPool

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(clientObject.Process);
ThreadPool.SetMaxThreads(2, 2);
```

Как это сделать через Thread

```
 Thread mythread = new Thread(clientObject.Process);
 mythread.Start();
```

Как ограничить количество максимально запущенных потоков? При этом потоки должны работать параллельно. Если кто-то понимает, буду очень признателен.

Comment: Просто не создавайте лишние потоки.

Comment: Это все понятно,тем не менее, как эту возможность реализовать? Задача стоит именно такая

Comment: А для того чтобы понять как это реализовать, надо знать что вы пытаетесь сделать и зачем вам вообще потоки.

Comment: Создайте свой аналог ThreadPool, который будет помнить, сколько вы создали потоков, и сколько из них работает в данный момент

Comment: Делаю tcp/ip clinet-server приложение, потоки используются для создания клиентов

Comment: Можете наглядно показать, как это будет выглядеть? Если честно, я слабо представляю себе. Без Task and ThreadPool. Только Thread, параллельно, с максимальным количеством работающих потоков

Comment: Как через семафоры сделать параллельность?

Comment: Можно сделать через таски, но для этого понадобится написать свой `TaskScheduler`. Правда это не даст 100% гарантии что кол-во потоков будет именно сколько вы желаете.